# How to incorporate Aforge.net on a web application

Tags: asp.net, winforms, web-applications, aforge

I have recently worked on a window form application using Aforge.net to process the images (Bitmap image) and to capture motion in the image. However i would like to integrate this window form application into my web application which i have developed using asp.net.

Any idea how i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You do **not** want to reference a WinForms application from your web application.

Move the image processing logic to a class library, and reference that library from both the WinForms and the web application.

Comment: Hi. I am not exactly processing an image as i am actually working on a motion sensing project which requires the use of Aforge. However as far as i know Aforge can only work on Window form and not web form.